# How to authenticate Android app to connect with Spotify?

Tags: java, android, spotify

I want to create my own (non-commercial) DDR app on my phone for fun that uses music from Spotify.

So far I've tried to follow the quickstart tutorial: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/quick-start/

- I have created a template app, with just a hello world screen in android studio.

[image]

- I have the spotify app installed, and I'm logged in with a premium account.
- I went to the spotify developer dashboard and registered my app. My app is called MyDDR for now.

[image]

- I have the redirect URI set to `192.168.1.23:5000/callback`, a flask server running on my PC. I tested it, and my phone can connect to it. I don't know if this is relevant since there is no traffic triggered by my code for now.
- Then I added my fingerprint and package name to the app I registered in the spotify developer dashboard. Here are my results from that:

  1. I created a signed bundle, with a keystore created following [this](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/quick-start/index%20copy/#register-app-fingerprints) tutorial.
     I only did the 'register app fingerprints' part, since the page seemed to be just an old version of the quickstart guide I was already following.
  2. Running the gradle task `signingReport` revealed the same SHA1 key that was in my keystore by checking it manually.

```
> Task :app:signingReport
Variant: release
Config: none
----------
Variant: debug
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\[name]\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: [removed]
SHA1: [mysha1key]
SHA-256: [removed]
Valid until: Wednesday, 8 September 2049
----------
[3 other variants, debugUnitTest, debugAndroidTest, releaseUnitTest]
```

I'm not familiar with signing apps, so I'm not sure it did it right.
As far as I understand it I only need to concern myself with debug right? I don't have plans releasing this to the play store.

3. Here is my android studio setup:

[image]
As you can see my package name is `com.example.myddr`

4. And finally I added my package name and fingerprint in the spotify developer dashboard:

[image]

- I had downloaded the Spotify Android SDK, by downloading the `spotify-app-remote-release-0.6.3.aar` file and adding it as a new module. I added the module/project to my build.gradle (Module: app) dependencies, together with gson, like the tutorial instructed.

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':spotify-app-remote')
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5"
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

- Now I was ready for the step 'Authorizing the user using the built-in auth flow'

This is the code so far

```java
package com.example.myddr;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.spotify.android.appremote.api.ConnectionParams;
import com.spotify.android.appremote.api.Connector;
import com.spotify.android.appremote.api.SpotifyAppRemote;

import com.spotify.protocol.client.Subscription;
import com.spotify.protocol.types.PlayerState;
import com.spotify.protocol.types.Track;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String CLIENT_ID = "2d6a5307b3024e7b9b32d52146150986";
    private static final String REDIRECT_URI = "http://192.168.1.23:5000/callback";
    private SpotifyAppRemote mSpotifyAppRemote;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        ConnectionParams connectionParams =
                new ConnectionParams.Builder(CLIENT_ID)
                        .setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI)
                        .showAuthView(true)
                        .build();

        SpotifyAppRemote.connect(this, connectionParams,
                new Connector.ConnectionListener() {

                    public void onConnected(SpotifyAppRemote spotifyAppRemote) {
                        mSpotifyAppRemote = spotifyAppRemote;
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "Connected! Yay!");

                        // Now you can start interacting with App Remote
                        connected();

                    }

                    public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
                        Log.e("MainActivity", throwable.getMessage(), throwable);

                        // Something went wrong when attempting to connect! Handle errors here
                    }
                });
    }

    private void connected() {
    }
}
```

However when running this I get a lot of warnings like this:

```
W/m.example.mydd: Unable to resolve Lcom/spotify/protocol/types/HelloDetails; annotation class 28
W/m.example.mydd: Unable to resolve Lcom/spotify/protocol/types/HelloDetails; annotation class 31
W/m.example.mydd: Unable to resolve Lcom/spotify/protocol/types/Info; annotation class 28
W/m.example.mydd: Unable to resolve Lcom/spotify/protocol/types/Info; annotation class 31
```

And finally an error:

```
E/MainActivity: {"message":"com.spotify.mobile.android.spotlets.appprotocol.model.AppProtocol$Message"}
    com.spotify.android.appremote.api.error.AuthenticationFailedException: {"message":"com.spotify.mobile.android.spotlets.appprotocol.model.AppProtocol$Message"}
        at com.spotify.android.appremote.api.LocalConnector.asAppRemoteException(LocalConnector.java:131)
        at com.spotify.android.appremote.api.LocalConnector.access$000(LocalConnector.java:35)
        at com.spotify.android.appremote.api.LocalConnector$1.onConnectionFailed(LocalConnector.java:111)
        at com.spotify.android.appremote.internal.SdkRemoteClientConnector$ConnectionTask.onPostExecute(SdkRemoteClientConnector.java:142)
        at com.spotify.android.appremote.internal.SdkRemoteClientConnector$ConnectionTask.onPostExecute(SdkRemoteClientConnector.java:75)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:695)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:180)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:712)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6898)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: com.spotify.protocol.client.error.RemoteClientException: {"message":"com.spotify.mobile.android.spotlets.appprotocol.model.AppProtocol$Message"}
        at com.spotify.protocol.client.RemoteWampClient.getRemoteClientException(RemoteWampClient.java:139)
        at com.spotify.protocol.client.RemoteWampClient.access$200(RemoteWampClient.java:16)
        at com.spotify.protocol.client.RemoteWampClient$1.onAbort(RemoteWampClient.java:44)
        at com.spotify.protocol.client.WampRouterImpl.routeAbort(WampRouterImpl.java:100)
        at com.spotify.protocol.client.WampRouterImpl.route(WampRouterImpl.java:26)
        at com.spotify.protocol.client.AppProtocolCommunicator.onData(AppProtocolCommunicator.java:78)
        at com.spotify.android.appremote.internal.RemoteServiceIo.handleMessage(RemoteServiceIo.java:113)
        at com.spotify.android.appremote.internal.RemoteServiceIo.access$000(RemoteServiceIo.java:47)
        at com.spotify.android.appremote.internal.RemoteServiceIo$IncomingHandler.handleMessage(RemoteServiceIo.java:91)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6898) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

This error means that I couldn't connect to Spotify due to an AuthenticationFailedException. Googling the error delivered no satisfying solutions. I only found people who had forgotten to register their fingerprint, but as far as I know I've done that. But I'm also suspicious that I did not do it correctly, because it seems fairly complicated.